# Fail to configure RabbitMQ in custom docker container due to :Error parsing configuration:

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I want to create a custom docker file for RabbitMQ. Unfortunately, the image failed to run due to error in config file. Here is how `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM rabbitmq:latest

COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq
```

And I just added basic configuration in `rabbitmq.conf` file:

```
default_pass = guest
default_user = guest
```

Then, we can build and run the image as follows

```
docker build -t my-rabbitmq .
docker run my-rabbitmq
```

But the image failed to run due to the following error:

```
2021-12-13 09:47:50.541977+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0> Error parsing configuration:
2021-12-13 09:47:50.566699+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>   - Syntax error in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf after line 1 column 1, parsing incomplete
2021-12-13 09:47:50.566739+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0> Are these files using the Cuttlefish format?

BOOT FAILED
===========
Error during startup: {error,failed_to_parse_configuration_file}

2021-12-13 09:47:50.570370+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>
2021-12-13 09:47:50.570370+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0> BOOT FAILED
2021-12-13 09:47:50.570370+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0> ===========
2021-12-13 09:47:50.570370+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0> Error during startup: {error,failed_to_parse_configuration_file}
2021-12-13 09:47:50.570370+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>     supervisor: {local,rabbit_prelaunch_sup}
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>     errorContext: start_error
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>     reason: failed_to_parse_configuration_file
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>     offender: [{pid,undefined},
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>                {id,prelaunch},
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>                {mfargs,{rabbit_prelaunch,run_prelaunch_first_phase,[]}},
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>                {restart_type,transient},
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>                {significant,false},
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>                {shutdown,5000},
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>                {child_type,worker}]
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577444+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>   crasher:
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     initial call: application_master:init/4
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     pid: <0.128.0>
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     registered_name: []
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     exception exit: {{shutdown,
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>                          {failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>                              failed_to_parse_configuration_file}},
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>                      {rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>       in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 142)
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     ancestors: [<0.127.0>]
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     message_queue_len: 1
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     messages: [{'EXIT',<0.129.0>,normal}]
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     links: [<0.127.0>,<0.44.0>]
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     dictionary: []
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     trap_exit: true
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     status: running
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     heap_size: 376
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     stack_size: 29
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>     reductions: 167
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>   neighbours:
2021-12-13 09:47:51.577992+00:00 [erro] <0.128.0>
2021-12-13 09:47:51.588037+00:00 [noti] <0.44.0> Application rabbitmq_prelaunch exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,failed_to_parse_configuration_file}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,failed_to_parse_configuration_file}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,failed_to_parse_configuration_file}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,sta

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...
```

I tried many tricks to create the config file but I always get the same error. I am not sure what is wrong with the above snippets. But creating the custom image should be very smooth.

Comment: I tried your steps and it works without problems you may have some strange character in your config file.

Comment: I have the same problem, and there are no strange character in the config file. What was the problem here?